# What is the difference between JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR4.exe andJetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR4.MSIL.exe

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, resharper

Resharper has several "TaskRunner", which it uses to run unit tests.

[image]

I wonder what are the difference between these version, particularly `JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR4.exe` and `JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR4.MSIL.exe`. When I compile my unit test assembly as "Class library", Resharper uses the former exe to run the unit test, and when I compile as "Console application", it used the latter. Something is strange because the unit test works in the latter case, but throw exception in the former.

Comment: Presumably one is x86, one is AnyCPU and one is x64.

Comment: Double-check the project settings for each project.  Console apps should be x86 and assemblies AnyCPU, which explains the two different runners.